# posting image with fb api getting error for new users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

I am trying give an option to Change their facebook cover from my website using facebook api.
Here is my code:

```
<script>
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        if (response)
        {

            fblogin();
            // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
        }
        else
        {
            // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
            alert('Kindly allow the My App to access the Facebook Account');
        }
    } else {
        // user is not logged in
        alert('You are not logged in Facebook Account');
    }
    }, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,offline_access,email'});


function fblogin()
{
    var imageName = 'myimage.png';
   jQuery.post("/facebook/index", {imageName:imageName}, function(data){    
    if(data)
    {
        parent.window.open("http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover="+data,'_blank');         
    } else {
alert('Please Login.');
}
    });
}

</script>
```

After login when i posted image name then :

```
require_once('/api/facebook/src/facebook.php');                 

    $this->objfacebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FB_SECRET_KEY,
        'fileUpload' => true,  
        'cookie' => true
    ));
$user_id = $this->objfacebook->getUser();
$access_token = $this->objfacebook->getAccessToken();
if ($user_id) {

$this->objfacebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

//Create an album
$album_details = array(
    'message'=> 'Cover Photo',
    'name'=> 'Created on My App'
);

$create_album = $this->objfacebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

$album_uid = $create_album['id'];

//Uploading Photo
$photo_details = array(
    'message'=> 'Cover Photo',
    'name'=> 'Created on My App'
);

$file = BASE_PATH."/public/images/".$_POST['imageName'];  //BASE_PATH - Actual path of image

$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

$upload_photo = $this->objfacebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

echo $upload_photo['id'];

exit();
}
```

For my old user it is working fine, they have no issue when they changed their Facebook cover. 
But when users come with their new facebook account to change their facebook they get a fetal error everytime.

I also have tried this with my new facebook account, it also gives me same Fetal Error.

I have no idea why is this happening for new users? Am i doing anything wrong here?

please give some idea.

Comment: can anybody me help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was happening because user didn't get any authorization popup to allow my app to publish data on their account..

it is fixed now. i have just updated my `fb api`. it works fine.